# Converting from Unicode to CP1252

Tags: java, unicode, cp1252

I am reading in an encrypted file in JAVA, with many irregular characters. The problem is that I am trying to decode it, however the decryption algorithms are implemented using CP1252 encoding, and not the native Java Unicode.

What I am doing essentially, is reading in the bytes from this file and saving them into a char[]. The reason I am not using a byte array is because their values can be unsigned, and so I wanted to make sure there was no loss of data because of it.

Anyway my question is that, is there a way to convert from Unicode encoding to CP1252 encoding, without converting the data into bytes?

An example of what I need is this.

**In CP1252: The value of € = 128 (I want this)**

**whereas in UNICODE: The value of € = 8364 (I read in this)**

If I were to convert it using bytes, the value would not hold constant, this is why I am using char[].

Comment: You need to use bytes.  Using bytes will not destroy data; signed/unsigned is just a matter of interpretation.

Comment: Does the encrypted file really contain *characters*? Sure it's not binary data? If it's binary, you can't treat it as text.

Comment: @SLaks, but if the values are not the same, byte max is 127, whereas the value is 128, how can they be the same.

Comment: @bzlm, how can I tell if it is binary data? And how should I treat it if it is? Also, for what I am doing currently it has been working for characters in which the Unicode and CP1252 values are equivalent, eg. 0-127

Comment: @user3280836: Values in [128,255] are interpreted as negative numbers due to the sign bit.

Comment: If you do not already understand this, you have no business developing crypto.  Security is **hard**.  You should use existing, proven, implementations.

Comment: @user3280836 look at the file with a text application. If it's just garbage, then it's not text. Then you have to use code that reads bits and bytes - not characters. Nothing string related, and nothing Encoding related. Encodings are just for representing *text* in various ways.

Comment: @bzlm It is binary, but that's actually what I have been doing, I've been reading them in one byte at a time but storing them in a char[]. I havent used any strings, however, is it possible to use byte arrays without losing data (if the value is out of the byte range)?

Comment: @user3280836: Yes; storing bytes in `byte`s **will not** lose data.

Comment: @user3280836, in Java, a char is an actual character in an alphabet (sort of), and the same goes for char[]s or strings. Don't use it for binary data - you'll run into problems sooner or later when working with sets of data. And trying to apply encodings to binary data (which is stored as "text") will inevitably garble the data.

Comment: Ok i have one more question, because essentially I have the code in C++ as well, however that code uses unsigned chars to read in the file. Is that because C++ does not support bytes? It works perfectly well in the C++ code

Comment: In C++, chars are perhaps just unsigned bytes. But that sounds like a very unmodern use of the word "character". Either way, in your specific case, the decryption code seems to *seemingly* take text as input when they are *actually* taking binary data disguised as CP1252. This is probably because CP1252 can represent every unsigned byte and can *technically* hence represent binary data. The decryption algorithms should have been designed to explicitly take binary data as input.

Comment: Ok i understand, so ultimately, I should be using binary data, regardless of signed/unsigned and the data should be perfectly fine?

Comment: C++'s `char` type is not Unicode-aware, and is essentially equivalent to Java's `byte`.

Comment: Ok thank you both so much! This is literally my first question (clearly) so I dont know how to upvote haha